# How can i add Order Estimator to Shopify product details page

Tags: javascript, shopify

Basically, I want to show **"FREE delivery {delivery-estimate}. Order within {time-counter}"**
above my add to cart button on my Shopify page. How can I do it?

Note:

1. delivery estimate should be after 7 days as of the current date.
2. time counter should refresh at 1:00 pm, and if the time is after 1:00 pm I want to add one more day to the estimated date.

Here is what I found before, but I cannot change it to the format I initially wanted.

```html
<script language="JavaScript"> 
function day(a) {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();

    // If after 3pm, add 1 day
    if(hours > 15) a++;

    var expectedDeliveryDate = addWeekdays(date, a);
    document.write(expectedDeliveryDate.toDateString() + ' with Standard Delivery');
}

function addWeekdays(fromDate, days) {
    var count = 0;
    while (count < days) {
        fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        if (fromDate.getDay() != 0 && fromDate.getDay() != 6) // Skip weekends
            count++;
    }
    return fromDate;
}

</script>

<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
day(1)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this and you can filter this according to your needs:

```js
const date = new Date()
const hours = date.getHours()

const newDate = new Date(date);
const deliveryEstimate = hours < 13 ? new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 7)) : new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 8))
const orderWithinValue = hours < 13 ? 13-hours : hours-13

console.log(`FREE delivery by ${deliveryEstimate.toISOString().split('T')[0]}. Order within ${orderWithinValue} hours`)
```

Your problem statement will have just a couple of "if condtions" and you need to handle them accordingly.

Comment: Glad I could help